# How to add parameter in Javascript and remove previous parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, parameters

I had a code that works but the problem is it just append the parameter 
instead of replacing it with a new parameter, Here is my working code:

```
jQuery('#input_1_11').change(function(){

        var type = jQuery('#input_1_11').val();
        if(type=='Inspection'){

            window.location.replace(window.location.href + "?Inspection");

        }
        else if(type=='Installation'){

            window.location.replace(window.location.href + "?Installation");
        }
        else{

            window.location.replace(window.location.href + "?Maintenance");
        }


    });
```

what currently happening is for example

```
www.test.com?Inspection
```

Then if  I click again the input11 it goes to the link

```
www.test.com?Inspection?Maintenance
```

What I need is to replace each ?parameter every change by user.

Comment: Try:  `window.location.hostname + "?Inspection"` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location):

`window.location.origin + "?Maintenance"`
instead of
`window.location.href + "?Maintenance"`

Comment: Note that `origin` only returns the domain. You'll most likely need to append the `path` to it as well, along with adding the `?` character.

Comment: At the end of OP question this is exactly what he is asking for.

Comment: True, but without the addition of `path` the solution is very brittle and easily broken. Regardless of that, this is the best method available; much better than hacking the URL around as a string.

Comment: I know, this is why i put the link to the `window.location.origin` for him to adjust the solution to his needings.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a thing - get the present url and split it into an array with `?` as parameter for `split`. Get the first element of that array. It will be the url without parameters.

```
jQuery('#input_1_11').change(function(){
        var type = jQuery('#input_1_11').val();
        var present = window.location.href.split("?");
        if(type=='Inspection'){
            window.location.replace(present[0] + "?Inspection");
        }
        else if(type=='Installation'){
            window.location.replace(present[0] + "?Installation");
        }
        else{
            window.location.replace(present[0] + "?Maintenance");
        }
});
```